# Invalid Date with moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, slider, momentjs

Considering this
http://jsfiddle.net/2a0hsj4z/4/, here as a snippet:

```js
moment.locale("en");

var start = moment("2010-10", "YYYY-MM");
var end = moment("2017-10", "YYYY-MM");

$("#chord_range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: start.format("x"),
    max: end.format("x"),
    from: start.format("x"),
    to: end.format("x"),
    prettify: function (num) {
        return moment(num, 'x').format("MMMM YYYY");
    }
});

var slider = $("#chord_range").data("ionRangeSlider");

$(".irs-slider").click(function() {
 console.log(slider.result.from);
})
```

```html
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/skin2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="chord_range" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Why do I get an `Invalid Date error` when I try to drag the left/right slider (start/end value)? On startup the date shows correctly. When you touch the slider, it breaks.
When I replace `var start = moment("2010-10", "YYYY-MM");` with `var start = moment("2012-10", "YYYY-MM");` it works:

```js
moment.locale("en");

var start = moment("2012-10", "YYYY-MM");
var end = moment("2017-10", "YYYY-MM");

$("#chord_range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: start.format("x"),
    max: end.format("x"),
    from: start.format("x"),
    to: end.format("x"),
    prettify: function (num) {
        return moment(num, 'x').format("MMMM YYYY");
    }
});

var slider = $("#chord_range").data("ionRangeSlider");

$(".irs-slider").click(function() {
 console.log(slider.result.from);
})
```

```html
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/skin2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="chord_range" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Why is that?

Comment: I copied your jsFiddle stuff into a snippet in the question. I don't know what you were doing, but it works and replicates the problem just fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I copy & pasted the `HTML` as well as the `JS` and added the external libraries (the ones that are linkd in jsfiddle link). That did not run - it gave me back an error.

Comment: "An error" isn't very useful information. In any case, again, I've done it for you. (All I did was copy and paste as well.) Good luck with the actual issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss the **step** option and step will be 1, 1 is too small for (option.max - option.min) and will cause error in ion rangeSlider.So you should set a large number for step option.

```
$("#chord_range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: start.format("x"),
    max: end.format("x"),
    from: start.format("x"),
    to: end.format("x"),
    step: 100000,
    prettify: function (num) {
      return moment(num, 'x').format("MMMM YYYY");
    }
});
```

Comment: but why does it work with a date higher than `2010`?

Comment: sorry for my poor english.In brief, . In ion rangeslider, there is a variable "this.coords.p_step"。 it is calculated by "(step * 100 / (options.max - options.min)).toFixed(9)". when step is too small or options.max - options.min is too large. the p_step will be 0, and it will cause error.